# Анимация элементов css

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть окно.
В ней рандомном расположены 3 элемента.
Как я могу просчитать анимацию, что бы при рандомном `top` элементы доходили до низа и возвращались в начальное положение (как это делает красный шар).
Позиция у элементов рандомная.

```css
#card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow: hidden; ///Для наглядности///*/
}

.bounce {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.type_1 {
  background: red;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  left: 10%;
  top: 0px;
}

.type_2 {
  background: blue;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  left: 25%;
  top: 20%;
}

.type_3 {
  background: green;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <div class="bounce type_1"></div>
  <div class="bounce type_2"></div>
  <div class="bounce type_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не с той стороны подходишь к задаче, как мне кажется. Я бы канвас заюзал. Если нет опыта с ним, [вот почитай](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript) пример простой игры. Там как раз за анимацию есть.

Comment: css calc() + animation должны по идее с этим справится но еслиб реализовал бы я сделал бы на js